How to use USD Hydra addon to import MaxterialX library into Blender？
I've already installed the plugin, but it says "Workspace Url is required, check Addon Preferences", causing Properties Editor > Materials Tab, Can't find the Material Library.


Can you provide the specific address of the workspace Url？The corresponding Material Library could not be found.

Here are the forum articles I referenced：
How to import MaterialX library into blender?

The question you linked has an accepted answer which mentions that USD Hydra can no longer perform the import.
